# AWS CLOUDWATCH in React Native Project?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to upload my react native application logs mechanism to the AWS CloudWatch. I am really confused and not getting which functions and which library to used. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out with this . I have already created account on the AWS , i am having Region, IAM Role, Identity Pool Id. It's just i need help how to implement things in the frontend.

Comment: There are quite a few libraries and solutions to that if you google "react frontend cloudwatch" - have you tried them, what is not working?

Comment: hye @luk2302, thanks for the reply. i tried using aws-cloudwatch-log-browser library and it works..!! Thanks for your help